# Store an Input of an Adjacency Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, vector, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to figure out how to store an adjacency matrix in c++.
Below is the code I have for how to go about this.

```
int main(){
        //get input
        int edges = -1, nodes = -1, source = -1;
        cin >> nodes >> edges >> source;
        vector<vector<int>> graph(nodes, vector<int>(nodes));'

        //get adjacency matrix stored
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < nodes; j++){
                        cin >> graph[i][j];
                }
        }

        //print out stored graph 
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++){
                for(int j=0; j < nodes; j++){
                        cout << graph[i][j];
                }
                cout << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The input is:

```
11 19        //first is num of nodes, second is num of edges
0            //source node 
01110000000
10111000000
11010100000
11100010000
01000110100
00101011000
00011100011
00000100110
00001001010
00000011100
00000010000
```

My goal is to get the same thing as an output.  However, when I go to print out the graph, I get the following:

```
11100000002147483647000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
```

This tells me the size of the graph is correct as it is 11x11 (node by node size).  However, it seems as though the code is only grabbing the values from the first line of the input.

Can anyone help me to understand where I went wrong?

Comment: When you do `cin >> graph[i][j]`, it doesn't know to read only a single character. It reads characters until it's no longer able to process it as an `int`, and then stops. So there's definitely some amount of garbage reading happening in your input loops.

Answer (score 3):

Your graph stores ints, so when you read in your graph data the rows are being parsed as integers.

`graph[0][0]` comes from the `01110000000` line, is parsed as `1'110'000'000`, which fits in a 32 bit integer.

`graph[0][1]` processes the next line, `10111000000`, which overflows (`10'111'000'000`) because it does not fit in a 32 bit integer. This will set the error condition on the stream and store `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` in the value. This is where the `2147483647` part comes from (`2'147'483'647`). The subsequent inputs all fail and set the input value to 0 because the fail bit is set on the stream.

To address this, you need to input characters. Something like

```cpp
char ch;
cin >> ch;
graph[i][j] = ch != '0';
```

to store 0 or 1 in your graph, treating any non-`0` input as a 1. You'll also want to skip the newlines at the end of each row.

Comment: Something like that but not exactly that, because you'll want to discard newlines entirely.

Comment: @NathanPierson That thought occurred to me when I started working on the answer, but it completely slipped my mind by the time I got to the end with the code.